# Show that multiplying two matrices of rank $n$ is not equal to the zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a homework problem with the given information that $A$ and $B$ are $3\times 3$ matrices, both with rank $2$. I have to show that $AB \ne 0$.

What I am interested in is what would constitute an appropriate formal proof for this question, and one that could be expanded to matrices with $n\times n$ dimension and rank $p\le n$.

My reasoning:
Rank denotes the number of linearly independent rows/columns --> $A, B$ have leading $1$'s in their first two rows in their RREF forms. Therefore, all of the possible combinations of where the leading 1s may fall in the matrices will never result in only $1\cdot 0$. But, this is obviously not a formalized proof and what I would like help with is showing this in an acceptable form. Thanks!

Comment: How about using the [Rank-Nullity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)?

Comment: @hardmath I understand that the rank-nullity theorem is rank(A) + nullity(A) = n, where n is the number of columns of a matrix A. What I don't understand is how to apply it to a problem of this sort. Any guidance?

Comment: nullity(A) + nullity(B) $\ge$ nullity(AB).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume $A,B$ are $n\times n$ matrices whose product $AB=0$.

Considered as matrix $A$ acting on the columns of $B$, the nullspace of $A$ has to contain the column space of $B$, in order to get to a zero product.

That means the nullity of $A$ (dimension of its nullspace) has to be at least the (column) rank of $B$.

Specialize to the data in your problem, where $A$ and $B$ have rank 2, and where by Rank-Nullity Theorem, the nullity of $A$ is ... ?

Comment: The nullity of A is 1, which provides a condition that contradicts the above. And, I assume we can do the reverse using B and the rows of A. Is that necessary?

Comment: One contradiction is enough, so it's not necessary.  The definition of nullity of $A$ is typically as I give it above (check your textbook), and the reason I point it out is that nullity isn't as "ambidexterous" as rank.  Nullity is the dimension of solutions to $Ax = 0$.